# Django Admin не шифрует пароль

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin, django-model

У меня есть модель CrmUser, которая наследуется от AbstractUser.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CrmUser(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    developer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
    pass
```

Проблема вот в чём - поля в админке показываются все как надо, но пароль не шифруется. В БД пользователь добавляется, в админке показывается, но через него не возможно войти на сайт(в админку также не пускает).
Если создаю пользователя через ***python manage.py createsuperuser*** - пользователь создается корректно. Через него можно войти и на сайт, и в админку(даже если убираю *суперстатус* - вход на сайт корректный.)

Если смотрю данные в БД(PostgreSQL) - у пользователей, которые созданы через ***createsuperuser*** пароль нормально зашифрован, у пользователей, созданых через админку - пароль показывается как обычный текст. Перелазил Гугл, не смог ничё надыбать, хелпаните, а?)

Comment: Вы как пароль в базу записываете при создании?

Comment: Ем... В смысле? 
Это делает сам Джанго, разве не? У меня же модель наследуется от AbstractUser, а там есть поле password

Comment: Я создаю пользователя ТОЛЬКО в админке, у меня нету окремого скрипта для этого.

Comment: Судя по документации надо переопределить set_password, ибо на AbstractUser оно не работает.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.set_password

Comment: Поонял... А как в коде это прописать?)

Comment: в наследнике пишете свою функцию соответствующую, которая делает всё правильно. Можете подсмотреть как она делается в случае с BaseUser или User в самой джанге.

Comment: А где могу почитать про эту функцию, а то чёт не врубаюсь))

Comment: Используйте стандартную админку UserAdmin, например?

Comment: Всмысле?
Вместо AbstractUser?

Comment: А, в admin.py, да? Ну, тогда нет тех полей, который я добавил в моделе(

Comment: Решение (нужно переназначить класс UserAdmin в файле admin.py): https://www.google.com.ua/amp/s/webdevblog.ru/sovremennyj-sposob-sozdanie-polzovatelskoj-modeli-user-v-django/amp/?espv=1

Comment: Да да, уже сделал, спасибо больше!)